# dotnet web api authentication with Keycloak

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, keycloak

I am running dotnet Web API with basic OAuth token authentication, but i have to configure this API to authenticate from Keycloak server.
I have to configure my asp.net mvc web api (.net framework 4.7) or dotnet core 3 api with keycloak. i have read the keycloak docs but there is no certain examples or adapters so that i can configure my REST API.

This is my startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(6),
                AllowInsecureHttp = false
            };

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        }
    }
```

This is the OAuthProvider Class

```
    public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private readonly string _publicClientId;

        public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
        {
            if (publicClientId == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(publicClientId));
            }
            _publicClientId = publicClientId;
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            string usernameVal = context.UserName;
            string passwordVal = context.Password;
            long convertusernametoid = long.Parse(usernameVal);
            var user = "userfromdb";

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            var username = "username";

            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthClaimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesClaimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(username);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthClaimIdentity, properties);

            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesClaimIdentity);
        }

        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            if (context.ClientId == null)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
        {
            if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
            {
                Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");
                if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
                {
                    context.Validated();
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> { };

            return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
        }
    }
```

Please help me with keycloak configuration to my Web Api.
Is it possible to update this code to get token from keycloak, if yes please guide me with configuration or any helpful resource.

Thank You.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: not yet and i changed my mind to use token authentication provided by OAuth, because i could not find any solution on internet nor the team updated the docs. if you find any solution please let me know.